# In Pandas, when selecting with "where", delete columns where condition is not met rather than filling with NaN

Tags: python, pandas

In Numpy, using `where` will give you a subset of the original array. For example,

```
import numpy as np
np.where(np.arange(5)>2)[0]
```

will return `array([3, 4])`. I'd like to do something similar with Pandas. However, if I define a similar DataFrame like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(5)).T
```

resulting a `df` which looks like

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  3  4
```

and apply

```
df.where(lambda x: x>2)
```

I get

```
    0   1   2  3  4
0 NaN NaN NaN  3  4
```

However, I'd like to get this:

```
    3  4
0   3  4
```

with the columns where the condition is not met omitted. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to filter out columns or rows? I think you want a dataframe with one column and multiple rows and then filter out the 'illegal' rows, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can call `dropna` passing `axis=1` to drop columns containing any `NaN` values:

```
In [272]:
df[df > 2].dropna(axis=1)

Out[272]:
   3  4
0  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the columns where the column names are smaller than 3, *provided the column names are integers*, if the column values are higher than 2.

```
print(df.drop(df[df.columns[df.columns < 3]] > 2, 1))
```

output:

```
   3  4
0  3  4
```